# Azure Function (Python) & Blob Storage Binding Error

Tags: azure, binding, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying the Azure Blob Bindings for Azure functions locally and i get errors running the example code:

host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
  },
  "extensions": {
      "blobs": {
          "maxDegreeOfParallelism": 4
      }
  }
}
```

**init**.py

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="BlobOutput1")
@app.route(route="file")
@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob",
                path="sample-workitems/test.txt",
                connection="blob__serviceUri")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
                path="newblob/test.txt",
                connection="blob__serviceUri")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(inputblob)
    return "ok"
```

I'm running the code in VS Code.
I have all prerequisites ready but this error appear:

```
[2023-05-12T23:12:53.216Z] Worker failed to load function: 'test' with functionId: '411ec582-2199-44a3-ac80-3e1be543cc33'.
[2023-05-12T23:12:53.219Z] Result: Failure
Exception: TypeError: <azure.functions.decorators.function_app.FunctionBuilder object at 0x000001AA650B3070> is not a module, class, method, or function.
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 376, in _handle__function_load_request
    self._functions.add_function(
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.10/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\functions.py", line 333, in add_function
    annotations = typing.get_type_hints(func)
  File "C:\Users\2643894\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\typing.py", line 1856, in get_type_hints
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a module, class, method, '
.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

A solution please to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I created a container in my storage account and uploaded a blob as below,
[image]

Then, I created another container in my storage account and uploaded a blob,
[image]

When I download the blob from first container in Azure portal it looks like below,
[image]

And I downloaded the blob from second container in Azure portal, it looks like below and there's no text in the blob:

[image]

Source code from [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=python-v2,in-process).

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging

app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="BlobOutput1")
@app.route(route="file")
@app.blob_input(arg_name="inputblob",
                path="sample-workitems/samplekam.txt",
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
@app.blob_output(arg_name="outputblob",
                path="newblob/demokam.txt",
                connection="AzureWebJobsStorage")
def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: str, outputblob: func.Out[str]):
    logging.info(f'Python Queue trigger function processed {len(inputblob)} bytes')
    outputblob.set(inputblob)
    return "ok"
```

**local.setting.json**:

```json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage-connction-string>",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
  }
}
```

Run your Blob storage trigger function like below:-

Click **fn + f5** or Click on **run > Debug** and it ran Successfully like below:

**Output:**
[image]

With the URL from the above output, I got the output in the browser,
[image]

Then, I downloaded the blob from the second container from Azure portal like below,
[image]

And the blob content looks like the blob from the first container,
[image]

***Steps to create a Blob Storage Trigger function in VS  code as below,***

I opened one **Folder** in my **Vs Code** and creates a new Function trigger like below:-

Click on create function and then select the folder,
[image]

[image]

[image]

It will create a project structure like below,
[image]

Then, I created an Azure Blob Storage Trigger function as below,
[image]

[image]

It will create a Blob Storage Trigger Function code in the function_app.py,
[image]

Then copy and paste the source code from [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?pivots=programming-language-python&tabs=python-v2,in-process) in the function_app.py like below,
[image]

**My local.settings.json:-**

```json
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "your-connection-string",
"AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing"
}
}
```

Run your Blob storage trigger function like below:-

Click **fn + f5** or Click on **run > Debug**, it will prompt to connect a storage account,

Click on Connect Storage Account,
[image]

Select the storage account from the list or you can create a new storage account,
[image]

Again Click **fn + f5** or Click on **run > Debug** and it ran Successfully like below:
**Output:**
[image]

With the URL from the above output, I got the output in the browser,
[image]

Then, I downloaded the blob from the second container from Azure portal like below,
[image]

And the blob content looks like the blob from the first container,
[image]

Comment: @PabloAndrésCisternaCárcamo Welcome, if it's helpful, can you give acceptance for the answer, it helps other too.